# how to separate the request uri into a for loop to break down variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, for-loop

i have the need to break down a REQUEST_URI to perform a few functions for each string between the slashes

the request that is passed from the url looks something like the below url however i cannot assign them  static variables as the url could get longer or shorter per different pages

https://www.domain.com/accounts/customers/details

what im looking to do is capture the "accounts/customers/details" section which i have done by this variable on the page

```
$requested_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // this outputs /accounts/customers/details
```

i wish to create a for loop extracting the information from between the brackets and displaying it on page like

```
accounts
customers
details
```

how can this be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$requested_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$seperate = explode("/",$requested_url); //this will explode in to array with "/" seperator
foreach($seperate as $seprt) { 
  echo $seprt."<br/>"; //it echo's each array variable seperately
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$requested_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$seperate = explode("/",$requested_url);

$count = 0;

foreach($seperate as $seprt) {
    $count++;
    if($count == count($seperate)){

         echo $seprt;
    }
}
```